# Document Viewer

Tags: windows, pdf, ocr, pdf-viewer, pdf-editor

Does anyone know of any good software choices that will either allow me to compare documents against a set of glyphs (character map behind pdf documents)?

Or if anyone knows of a good OCR software that can read and compare documents? It must run on Windows, and I've no price margin.

Comment: "*compare documents*": What kind of comparison?

Comment: "*compare documents against a set of glyphs*": Do you mean checking whether this document contains any characters from that set? Or whether it contains characters that are not in that set? Or something else?

Answer (score 1):

If you are wanting to work with with a commercial OCR SDK you could check out the [LEADTOOLS OCR SDK](https://www.leadtools.com/sdk/ocr). You can easily OCR a document in just few lines of code, see below.

```
// Initialize the OCR engine
ocrEngine = OcrEngineManager.CreateEngine(OcrEngineType.Advantage, 

// Startup the engine
ocrEngine.Startup(null, null, null, @"C:\LEADTOOLS 19\Bin\Common\OcrAdvantageRuntime");

using (IOcrDocument ocrDocument = ocrEngine.DocumentManager.CreateDocument())
{
 //Load image
 RasterImage image = ocrEngine.RasterCodecsInstance.Load(file, 0, CodecsLoadByteOrder.Rgb, 1, -1);
 //Add pages
 ocrDocument.Pages.AddPages(image, 1, -1, null);

 //Recognize Page
 ocrDocument.Pages.Recognize(null);

 //Save Output 
 ocrDocument.Save(outPut, Leadtools.Forms.DocumentWriters.DocumentFormat.Text, null);
}
```

You can also find an [OCR HTML5/JavaScript Interactive Demo](http://demo.leadtools.com/JavaScript/OCR/index.html) if you are interested in testing this out with your file. This SDK will work on Windows, Linux, Mac, Android, WinRT and iOS.

Disclaimer: I am an employee of this product

Comment: Do you have an email contact available?

Comment: Yes of course, please contact us at support@leadtools.com with any questions you may have